# Checking two tables if they have the same value (and adding a checkmark)

Tags: php, mysql, database, if-statement

I wanna do the following: Check if a user is already in the second table. If the user is, I get back the echo: "User is in database" and it should also add a value to the table, when the user is or is not in the database. As of now it seems to do the right thing, but doesn't change the value next to user.

```
<?php

$DB_HostName = "localhost";
$DB_Name = "db";
$DB_User = "user";
$DB_Pass = "pw";
$DB_Table = "connection";
$DB_Table2 = "contacts";

$con = mysql_connect($DB_HostName,$DB_User,$DB_Pass) or die (mysql_error()); 
mysql_select_db($DB_Name,$con) or die(mysql_error()); 

$query = "SELECT User FROM $DB_Table left join $DB_Table2 on User = Number";

if ($result) {

    if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {

echo "This user is already in database";
mysql_query("INSERT INTO $DB_Table2 (Answer)
VALUES ('http://myserver/thumbsup.png')");        
}
else {
echo "This user isn't in the database";
mysql_query("INSERT INTO $DB_Table2 (Answer)
VALUES ('http://myserver/thumbsdown.png')");    
}
}
mysql_close($con);

?>
```

Comment: Shouldnt `$table_id` and `$table_id2` be `$DB_Table` and `$DB_Table2` in your first query?

Comment: `$table_id` and `$table_id2` are undefined?

Comment: Adding `http://myserver/thumbsdown.png` for every user seems like a waste of space and resources

Comment: Why for every user? Other one gets thumbsup. In addition its just the link to the picture, not the picture itself. And I edited the tables, dont know how I missed that.

Answer (score 1):

When looking at the code, it's hard to see what you're trying to do here. Anyhow, I do think you need to check **which** user you're looking from the table.

```
$query = "SELECT User FROM $table_id left join $table_id2 on User = Number";
```

should be more like

```
$query = "SELECT User FROM $DB_Table left join $DB_Table2 on User = Number where $DB_Table.User = " . $_SESSION['userid'];
```

if you have authenticated the user some way and the users id number is in a session variable called 'userid'. You clearly have not thought this through, because you're adding links to the second table with default values on every other key.

Comment: First of all thanks for your input. To clear things up: I am trying to check if there is a entry for the user in DB_Table2 and one. If this is the case You get a thumbs up. If not you get a thumbs down.